# How to get row count in an Excel file using POI library?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

Guys I'm currently using the POI 3.9 library to work with excel files. I know of the `getLastRowNum()` function, which returns a number of rows in an Excel file.

The only problem is `getLastRowNum()` returns a number with the count starting from 0.

So if an Excel file uses the first 3 rows, `getLastRowNum()` returns 2.
If an Excel file has just 1 row, `getLastRowNum()` returns 0.

The problem occurs when the Excel file is completely empty. `getLastRowNum()` still returns 0, so I cannot determine if the Excel file has 1 row of data, or if its empty.

So how can I detect if an Excel file is empty or not ?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try [Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getPhysicalNumberOfRows%28%29)

Comment: +1 Marcias. Just that if one deletes cells by just pressing Delete, then seems like rows still exists physically and old count is returned.

Comment: Well, I think that if you'd like to count rows that actually have some non empty value, you'll need to iterate over it by yourself. I'm not sure, but I understand that this method returns number of rows that have ever been kind of "declared".

Comment: WARNING: If the sheet has blank rows then  getPhysicalNumberOfRows does not include them in the count it returns.  However,  getLastRowNum also does exactly what it says on the tin.  So to iterate over all the rows you need to use getLastRowNum+1 as the upper bound in your iteration loop - taking care to handle rows which may not exist.

Answer (score 9):

Since `Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` does not count empty rows and `Sheet.getLastRowNum()` returns 0 both if there is one row or no rows, I use a combination of the two methods to accurately calculate the total number of rows.

```
int rowTotal = sheet.getLastRowNum();

if ((rowTotal > 0) || (sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0)) {
    rowTotal++;
}
```

Note: This will treat a spreadsheet with one empty row as having none but for most purposes this is probably okay.

Answer (score 5):

There are two Things you can do

use

```
int noOfColumns = sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
```

or

```
int noOfColumns = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
```

There is a fine difference between them

1. Option 1 gives the no of columns which are actually filled with contents(If the 2nd column of 10 columns is not filled you will get 9)
2. Option 2 just gives you the index of last column. Hence done `'getLastCellNum()'`

Answer (score 2):

If you do a check

```
if
(getLastRowNum()<1){
 res="Sheet Cannot be empty";
return
}
```

This will make sure you have at least one row with data except header. Below is my program which works fine. Excel file has three columns ie. ID, NAME , LASTNAME

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row header = sheet.getRow(0);
        int n = header.getLastCellNum();
        String header1 = header.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        String header2 = header.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        String header3 = header.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
        if (header1.equals("ID") && header2.equals("NAME")
                && header3.equals("LASTNAME")) {
            if(sheet.getLastRowNum()<1){
                System.out.println("Sheet empty");
                         return;
            }   
                        iterate over sheet to get cell values
        }else{
                          SOP("invalid format");
                          return;
                          }
```

Comment: The [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum) note that it's zero based. So `getLastRowNum()` would return 0 for when there's no columns or when there's only 1 (header in your case). So for checking if there's any rows `getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` should also be used.

Comment: also the [HSSF sheet docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum()) have some more content regarding this subject.

Answer (score 1):

getLastRowNum() return index of last row.

So if you wants to know total number of row = getLastRowNum() +1.

I hope this will work.

```
int rowTotal = sheet.getLastRowNum() +1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` does not involve some empty rows.
If you want to loop for all rows, do not use this to know the loop size.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i had where i used getPhysicalNumberOfRows() method to get actual data. but my uploading sheet was containing blank rows too then it causing problem and missing last some rows.

I have used sheet.getLastRowNum() +1 for outer loop for rows count and inner i used getPhysicalNumberOfRows().

It red whole and working fine.

Answer (score -1):

To find last data row, in case you created table template in excel where it is filled partially or in between rows are empty.
Logic:

```
int count = 0;
int emptyrow=0;
int irow=0;
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
    if (count != 0 && !checkIfRowIsEmpty(row)) { }
    else{
        if(count!=0 && emptyrow==irow){
            emptyrow++;
        }else{
            emptyrow=0;
            irow=0;
        }
    }
    if(emptyrow>0){
        irow++;
    }
    if(emptyrow>3){
        break;
    }
    count++;
}
```