# get number of rows of a particular column in given excel using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl

I've tried a couple of for loops, but that doesn't help me. Can anyone help me on this?

Following is there for to get a number of columns of a particular row in given excel using Java. But I want vice versa.

```
int noOfColumns = sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
int noOfColumns = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail.  What library are you using to access spreadsheets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get row count in an Excel file using POI library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234486/how-to-get-row-count-in-an-excel-file-using-poi-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the methods you've mentioned, I'd guess you're using Apache POI.
So assuming **sh** is your active sheet object and **columnIndex** is the index of the column you're inspecting:

```
int lastRow = sh.getLastRowNum();
    while (lastRow >= 0 && sh.getRow(lastRow).getCell(columnIndex) == null) {
        lastRow--;
    }
int columnSize = lastRow + 1;
```